# Преобразование в сравнении bool

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, преобразование-типов, promotions

Есть ли в данном коде преобразование `bool` к `int` **в самом сравнении**? Если есть, то почему так сделано, ведь код потенциально медленнее из-за преобразований?

```
std::cout << (true == true) << '\n';
```

Comment: а как выводить  bool иначе?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос (хотя в заголовке изначально это было написано). То есть есть ли преобразование в `(true == true)`?

Comment: в самом сравнении нет никакого преобразования

Comment: @ARHovsepyan почему? Ведь должно быть promotion к инту насколько я понимаю

Comment: @user7860670 и что что одинаковые? Разве для `bool` и `short` есть отдельные операторы сравнения? Я ссылаюсь на вот [это](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.built#13), тут сказано *promoted arithmetic types*. Можете указать где эти операторы отдельно для bool определены?

Comment: @user7860670 А теперь я начну цепляться :) - а если типа `byte ptr []` или `al` перед сравнением будет переведено в `eax` - то это приведение или нет? :) clang это делает, VC++ тоже...

Comment: @AlexF честно говоря, не понял ваш комментарий

Comment: хмм, по факту действительно, встроенные операторы сравнения реализуются только для преобразованных типов, и к обеим операндам тут сначала будет применяться повышающее преобразование, а уже потом сравнение. надо бежать исправлять кучу сломанного кода...

Comment: @user7860670 вопрос почему бы не сделать отдельные сравнения для маленьких типов, а именно для арифметических операторов (+,-,...) уже делать promotion?

Comment: @AlexF приведите линк, который вы считаете тут подходит. "код на ассемблере" никак не относится к вопросу как раз, там наверняка будет вшитая константа и никакого сравнения

Comment: Ну это не ко мне вопрос, будь моя воля, неявных преобразований в языке вообще бы не было, но зато был бы полный набор арифметических операторов (с контролем переполнения и т.п.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внезапно преобразование обязательно будет для обоих операндов.

Среди встроенных операторов для целочисленных типов оператор ==, как и другие, задается только для целочисленных типов после повышения:

> **16.6 Built-in operators[over.built]**
> 2 In this subclause, the term promoted integral type is used to refer to those integral types which are preserved by integral promotion (including e.g. int and long but excluding e.g. char). Similarly, the term promoted arithmetic type refers to floating types plus promoted integral types. [ Note: In all cases where a promoted integral type or promoted arithmetic type is required, an operand of enumeration type will be acceptable by way of the integral promotions.  — end note ]
> ...
> 13 For every pair of promoted arithmetic types L and R, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> LR      operator*(L, R);
> LR      operator/(L, R);
> LR      operator+(L, R);
> LR      operator-(L, R);
> bool    operator<(L, R);
> bool    operator>(L, R);
> bool    operator<=(L, R);
> bool    operator>=(L, R);
> bool    operator==(L, R);
> bool    operator!=(L, R);
> where LR is the result of the usual arithmetic conversions between types L and R.

При этом при вызове такого оператора применяются *обычные арифметические преобразования*:

> **7.4 Usual arithmetic conversions [expr.arith.conv]**
> 1 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions, which are defined as follows:
> — (1.1) If either operand is of scoped enumeration type (9.7.1), no conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same type, the expression is ill-formed.
> — (1.2) If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted to long double.
> — (1.3) Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.
> — (1.4) Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.
> — (1.5) Otherwise, the integral promotions (7.3.6) shall be performed on both operands.

для последнего пункта также дается пояснение:

> As a consequence, operands of type bool , char8_t , char16_t , char32_t , wchar_t , or an enumerated type are converted to some integral type.

Comment: По этому ответу, я понимаю, что bool будет преобразован (converted) в какой то интергральный тип (к примеру в int),  а для него не нужен promoted.

Comment: @KoVadim что вы подразумеваете под "а для него не нужен promoted"? promoted тип - это тип, который получится из bool или другого "мелкого" типа после integral promotions (которое например представляет собой преобразование в int), тип для которого существует встроенный оператор ==.

Comment: "As a consequence, operands of type bool , char8_t , char16_t , char32_t , wchar_t , or an enumerated type are converted to some integral type." - написано, что bool может быть преобразован в какой то интегральный тип. int - это интегральный тип.

Comment: Если есть, то интересен также ответ на вторую часть вопроса. Правда ли что promotion может делать код медленее или это сугубо на уровне компиляции? А ещё минимальный пример вот этого "надо бежать исправлять кучу сломанного кода" было бы интересно увидеть. Какой код это может сломать, то есть.

Comment: @KoVadim Сослагательного наклонения, "может", там нет. Преобразование обязательное.

Comment: @BEE я отношу неявные преобразования к ошибкам, и мне очень импонирует язык Ada

Comment: я имел ввиду, что bool может быть конвертирован в int, может short, или ещё какой то разрешенный тип. Я привожу к тому, что компилятор может выбрать преобразование в int

Comment: @KoVadim Для `bool` предусмотрено повышение только в `int`, а вот уже потом при необходимости (которая при сравнении bool с bool отсутствует, так как справа и слева получится int) полученный int может быть повышен дальше до unsigned int и т.п. как то прописано в Usual arithmetic conversions (которые я привел в ответе не полностью)

Comment: а зачем повышать до unsigned int?

Comment: @KoVadim по идее это произойдет, если будет сравнение bool с unsigned int например

Comment: но у нас сравнение двух булов?

Comment: @KoVadim так я же написал выше - **при необходимости (которая при сравнении bool с bool отсутствует, так как справа и слева получится int)**

Comment: отсюдова делаем вывод. при сравнении двух булов они будут **конвертированы** в int, а для него не требуется promotion. Это и есть полный ответ на вопрос

Comment: @KoVadim что-то вас не туда понесло... promotion - это и есть конвертирование. Promotion для bool описано как A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type int , with false becoming zero and truebecoming one.

Comment: тогда зачем два разных слова?

Comment: @KoVadim Ну это не ко мне вопрос... я бы вообще выкинул из языка все неявные преобразования, в т.ч. integral promotions.

Comment: @KoVadim, «"As a consequence, operands of type bool , char8_t , char16_t , char32_t , wchar_t , or an enumerated type are converted to some integral type." - написано, что bool может быть преобразован в какой то интегральный тип...», насколько я понимаю, здесь имеется в виду, что каждый тип из приведённого списка конвертируется в некоторый другой целочисленный тип, согласно правилам integral promotions. Тип `bool` в `int`; тип `char16_t` в `int`, или `unsigned int`, или в `long` и т.д. Просто авторы не стали копировать в сноску всё содержимое главы integral promotions, а написали кратко.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в вопросе в том, что он предполагает, что само преобразование может быть и может быть дорогим. Как только это утрясти, все стает на свои места.

Под капотом [bool](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) - это любой тип, в котором компилятор может сохранить один бит. И это обычно char (то есть один байт, хотя компилятор волен взять и 4 байта. знаковый или нет - не важно, так как нам нужен только ноль и что то отличное от нуля, обычно там 1). И что бы сравнить два байтовых (или 4 байтовых) значения, компилятору не нужно делать promotion, у него уже два числа одного типа. Он прекрасно умеет сравнивать два числа.

**Полезные ссылки:**

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

> Boolean type bool - type, capable of holding one of the two values: true or false. The value of sizeof(bool) is implementation defined and might differ from 1.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

> the type bool can be converted to int with the value false becoming ​0​ and true becoming 1.

то есть, может быть сконвертирован. Но не обязан.

И на самый конец:) Открываем стандарт, я взял документ n3337.pdf, глава "4.5 Integral promotions" - прям как для вопроса. И там есть такое замечание

> A prvalue of an integer type other than bool, char16_t, char32_t, or wchar_t whose integer conversion rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if int can represent all the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type unsigned int.

опять же, видим, что для bool не нужно делать ничего специально.

> A prvalue of type bool **can be converted** to a prvalue of type int, with false becoming zero and true becoming one.

то есть, может быть, но нет слов have to/must.

Comment: по ссылке не написано то, что у вас в ответе

Comment: по какой из ссылок и что именно там написано?

Comment: "Под капотом bool" - тут ссылка, но по ней нет того, что вы говорите далее. Например "это обычно char" или "компилятору не нужно делать promotion". Ну или я не нашёл, укажите тогда подробнее если не сложно

Comment: по моей ссылке написано "Boolean type
bool - type, capable of holding one of the two values: true or false. The value of sizeof(bool) is implementation defined and might differ from 1."

Comment: Да, и почему из этого следует "это обычно char" или "компилятору не нужно делать promotion"?

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1`. Если сильно придираться к словам, то тут правильнее сказать, что там однобайтовое. Но в данном случае это абсолютно не важно.

Comment: "sizeof(char) == 1" && "sizeof(bool) is implementation defined and might differ from 1" => "это обычно char " ???

Comment: ну не строка же.

Comment: по ссылке https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.built#13 встроенные оператор == существуют только для promoted типов, так что без конвертирования не обойтись

Comment: я не вижу там "только". Там сказано, что для каждой пары "повышаемых" (кстати, пары - значит типы разные?) типов, есть такие операторы. Но там не написано, что их нет для других типов.

Comment: @KoVadim promot**ed**

Comment: Не повышаемых, а повышенных. Там в начале еще пояснение дается *In this subclause, the term promoted integral type is used to refer to those integral types which are preserved by integral promotion (including e.g. int and long but excluding e.g. char).* там явно написано, что для других типов их нет, так как все, что есть, перечислены

Comment: @KoVadim приведённые вами последние ссылки говорят лишь о том, что существуют ситуации, в которых будет promotion. Из этого не следует что в указанной в вопросе ситуации promotion опциональный.

Comment: то есть Вы хотите от Страуструпа подверждение, что здесь не будет промоушинга? хотя я думаю, и его ответ не будет для Вас ответом.

Comment: @KoVadim я хочу любую ссылку, которая доказывает что в указанной в вопросе ситуации promotion опциальный. Ведь это ваш итоговый вывод, так?

Comment: Мой итоговый вывод, что Вы немного нагнетаете и не уважаете окружающих.

Comment: @KoVadim, "...то есть, может быть, но нет слов have to/must." **Не** согласен с вашей интерпретацией. Глава `Integral promotions` говорит, что в принципе есть такое преобразование, которое позволяет преобразовать тип `bool` в тип `int` и называется такое преобразование `integral promotions`. Эта глава не говорит, "хочешь преобразовывай, не хочешь, не преобразовывай", она говорит, что если надо преобразовать, то это можно сделать. Теперь смотрим [Usual arithmetic conversions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5): ...

Comment: "Otherwise, the integral promotions ([conv.prom]) **shall be performed** on both operands. 56". Здесь вполне ясно сказано, что если оба операнда имеют целочисленный тип, то они обязаны подвергнуться integral promotions. То есть тип `bool` **должен** быть преобразован в тип `int`. Также смотрим сноску 56: "As a consequence, operands of type bool, char8_­t, char16_­t, char32_­t, wchar_­t, or an enumerated type are converted to some integral type.". Она явно говорит, что тип `bool` будет конвертирован в другой тип.

Comment: Также смотрим [Equality operators](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#7): "If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the **usual arithmetic conversions are performed** on both operands". Оператор сравнения **требует** применения usual arithmetic conversions к своим операндам, а usual arithmetic conversions **требуют** применения integral promotions к целочисленным операндам, а integral promotions, применённые к типу `bool`, преобразуют его в `int`.

Comment: там рядом есть ещё примечание - http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.arith.conv#1.5.1 - If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed. -  все смотрят  на него и понимают, что если на вход пришло два була и даже если их преобразовали в int, то это никак не повлияет на результат.

Answer (score -2):

Почему нет преобразований?.. Хотя бы потому, что `true и false`  макросы:

```
#define false   0
#define true    1
```

Препроцессор сам вставляет `0 или 1`, и дело до компилятора даже не доходит, чтобы было какое то преобразование

Comment: преобразование тут все-такие есть, а true и false - это ни разу не макросы, а ключевые слова

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.bool

Comment: имхо вы с `_Bool` перепутали

Comment: bool и есть  _Bool из С:  определен так  `#define bool  _Bool`

Comment: @ARHovsepyan метка c++